# How to stop VLOOKUP formula from giving mis-matches / false positives?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

I am trying to collect data from three tabs together into one row, using a shared "key" of Address.

You can see my sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G2p2TvplOGQSgDV0PP-_d-gMRcD_JbLlkKw8aOXO9g0/edit?usp=sharing

In the front sheet called "Merged Responses" I am trying to use VLOOKUPS to do this.

Here is my formula for one cell in particular:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,'Step 2'!$B$2:$E,2)
```

The first row seems to work, but then it breaks down for subsequent rows.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, or possibly just not understanding how VLOOKUP is meant to work... Currently getting mis-matched data and false positives as seen in spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your cell example (Merged Responses E2 try:

```
=iferror(vlookup(D2,'Step 2'!$B$2:$E,2,false))
```

That looks for an exact match in a non-sorted column. The same approach should work in your other vlookups. iferror will show blank if a match is not found.

Comment: Thanks @Ed Nelson!